# Passing a enum as a function parameter | C

Tags: c, function, parameters, enums

I need to track where the function is calling too, so I made an enum with a list of the drivers I wish to track.

```
enum FPGA_IO_Type{

   A429_RX = 0,

   A429_TX = 1,

   A717_RX = 2,

   A717_TX = 3

};
```

now I want to put it as a function parameter

```
static void _function(otherData, enum FPGA_IO_Type)
```

and each function call looks something like this

```
_function(data, A429_RX);
```

However I get an error for "Parameter name omitted".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving it a name identifier, should be like:

```
static void _function(otherData, enum FPGA_IO_Type type)
```

likewise when you define a `struct`

```
struct Abc
{
   ...
}
```

you can put it as a parameter such as

```
void function(struct Abc abc)
{

}
```

Here `enum FPGA_IO_Type` and `struct Abc` are the types of the parameter and `type` and `abc` are the identifiers.

Comment: Another option is using typedef declaration: `typedef enum FPGA_IO_Type { ... } FPGA_IO_Type_t` so the varilable is simply `FPGA_IO_Type_t`

Comment: @Filippo Yes indeed